# ActionBarSherlock set gradient background

Tags: android

Hi i'm wanting to set a gradient background on ActionBarSherlock i'm currently setting this in the theme as a shape drawable but when i run it it just has a white background does anyone know what i'm doing wrong or how to do this?

heres my style(i have declared this in the manifest file)

```
  <style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">

    <item name="background">@drawable/bg_actionbar</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_actionbar</item>
 </style>

<style name="Theme.SherlockCustom" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>

</style>
```

and heres my drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle"> 
    <gradient 
    android:type="radial" 
    android:gradientRadius="400" 
    android:startColor="#FF0000" 
    android:endColor="#0000FF" /> 
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is cool only that the xml gradient element should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle"> 
    <gradient 
    android:angle="270" 
    android:startColor= "#FF0000"
    android:centerColor="#FF0000" 
    android:endColor="#0000FF" /> 
</shape>
```